# Auth service using Web Api, membership provider, and SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I am looking to write an auth service using Web Api, and SQL Server for authenticating and authorizing users on my .net site, but ios and Android apps as well. I'm speculating that basic authentication over SSL is the easiest way to go, but I'm pretty new to this whole section of .net. I'm having trouble finding some clear tutorials that explain how to write such a service. Can anyone point me to some resources on how to do this? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is the site you are securing also implemented in .NET?  Is there a reason why the authentication and authorization functionality would be done through Web API?

In general, writing an authentication/authorization service is not recommended, unless you really know what you are doing.  Look at this [site](http://www.thinktecture.com/).  There are links to open source identity server that may fit your needs.

Comment: I guess I need to know what the best practices are for writing services as well. The service in question will be hit by a .net site, but more than likely an ios native app, possibly Android as well. Theoretically, only registered users will be able to access the service, hence why I want some authentication/authorization built in. Do you advise that authentication be done on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think you need to look OAuth implementation in .NET.

[Here](https://vimeo.com/user22258446/review/79095048/9a4d62f61c) is a video to give you some background on Web API security.

I also suggest getting a trial subscription to [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training) training and check out the courses on Web API security.

You may want to target the latest release of Web API 2.0 from Microsoft, it has the most features you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful for you:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api